# Using map to iterate through two arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently in React, I am using `array.map(function(text,index){})` to iterate through an array. But, how am I going to iterate through two arrays simultaneously using map?

**EDIT**

```
var sentenceList = sentences.map(function(text,index){
            return <ListGroupItem key={index}>{text}</ListGroupItem>;
        })
return (
     <div>
       <ListGroup>
        {sentenceList}
      </ListGrouup>
   </div>
);
```

Like, in this I want icons to be prepended with every iteration. And I'm planning to have those icons in another array. So, thats why iterate two arrays.

Comment: Are you using array.map just to iterate ? What are you doing inside the map function ?

Comment: What do you mean iterate through two arrays simultaneously? As in you want the mapping function to take `(member1, member2)` arguments?

Comment: Check edit, does it make my point clear?

Comment: @Aron yes precisely, member 1 for fetching images, member 2 for fetching text.

Comment: Are the two arrays guaranteed to have the same number of members?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If at all possible, I would recommend storing the text alongside the images in an array of objects, eg:

```
const objects = [{text: 'abc', image: '/img.png' }, /* others */];
```

that way you can just iterate through the array and select both members at the same time, for example:

```
objects.map(item => (<Component icon={item.image} text={item.text} />) )
```

If this isn't possible then just map over one array and access the second array's members via the current index:

```
sentences.map((text, index) => {
    const image = images[index];
    return (<Component icon={image} text={text} />);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Are the both arrays of same length? You can do something like below if your intention is to combine both in some way.

```
array.map(function(text,index){
   return text + ' ' + array2[index]
})
```

In your case:

```
var sentenceList = sentences.map(function(text,index){
            return <ListGroupItem key={index}>{text} <img src={icons[index]} /i> </ListGroupItem>;
        })
return (
     <div>
       <ListGroup>
        {sentenceList}
      </ListGrouup>
   </div>
);
```

Notice, How Icon src is being assigned. The idea is that access icons array with the same index to get a corresponding icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with built-in `Array.prototype` methods, but you can use something like this:

```
function map2(arr1, arr2, func) {
    return arr1.map(
        (el, i) => { return func(el, arr2[i]); }
    );
}
```

(Of course, `arr1` and `arr2` are expected to have the same length)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, what you're looking for is a `zip` function, such as the one that lodash provides. Much like a real zipper, it combines two things of the same length into one:

```
const zipped = _.zip(sentences, icons);

return (
  <div>
    <ListGroup>
      {zipped.map(([sentence, icon], index) => (
        <ListGroupItem key={index}><Icon icon={icon} /> {text}</ListGroupItem>;
      ))}
    </ListGroup>
 </div>
);
```

Note, this is doing more iterations than are technically needed. If performance is an issue, you may want a solution that's a bit smart (not really in scope for your question though).