# React Native. How do I add a for loop that displays data(eg. <Text>) inside render method

Tags: react-native

So I have there 4 Arrays and what i'm trying to do is render each element from that array to my screen.Subtotal=[
  0,
  1850,
  2310.91,
]
Tax_total=[
  0,
  238.06,
  369.1,
]
Total=[
  0,
  2088.06,
  2680.01,
]
Orders=[
  0,
  7,
  15,
] I am a newbie and would like to know any alternate method to efficiently render these values. The code below works, but is very lengthy so is it possible to have a for loop inside the render return method.

Code:

```
      <View>
        <View style={styles.container} flexDirection="row">
          <Text style={styles.title}>Subtotal: </Text>
          <Text style={styles.Body}>${this.state.subtotal[0]}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container} flexDirection="row">
          <Text style={styles.title}>Tax Total: </Text>
          <Text style={styles.Body}>${this.state.tax_total[0]}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container} flexDirection="row">
          <Text style={styles.title}>Total: </Text>
          <Text style={styles.Body}>${this.state.total[0]}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container} flexDirection="row">
          <Text style={styles.title}>Total Orders: </Text>
          <Text style={styles.Body}>{this.state.total_orders[0]}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.container} flexDirection="row">
          <Text style={styles.title}>Subtotal: </Text>
          <Text style={styles.Body}>${this.state.subtotal[1]}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container} flexDirection="row">
          <Text style={styles.title}>Tax Total: </Text>
          <Text style={styles.Body}>${this.state.tax_total[1]}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container} flexDirection="row">
          <Text style={styles.title}>Total: </Text>
          <Text style={styles.Body}>${this.state.total[1]}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container} flexDirection="row">
          <Text style={styles.title}>Total Orders: </Text>
          <Text style={styles.Body}>{this.state.total_orders[1]}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.container} flexDirection="row">
          <Text style={styles.title}>Subtotal: </Text>
          <Text style={styles.Body}>${this.state.subtotal[2]}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container} flexDirection="row">
          <Text style={styles.title}>Tax Total: </Text>
          <Text style={styles.Body}>${this.state.tax_total[2]}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container} flexDirection="row">
          <Text style={styles.title}>Total: </Text>
          <Text style={styles.Body}>${this.state.total[2]}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container} flexDirection="row">
          <Text style={styles.title}>Total Orders: </Text>
          <Text style={styles.Body}>{this.state.total_orders[2]}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using map to iterate through two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42925805/using-map-to-iterate-through-two-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I am writing code right here in the stack overflow text area, this is pseudo code, it doesn't work as-is.

First you need to create a separate component for the title/Body part.

You can call the component TotalItem and it would have a render methode like this:

```
render() {
        <View style={styles.container} flexDirection="row">
          <Text style={styles.title}>{this.props.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.Body}>{this.props.amount}</Text>
        </View>
}
```

Just doing this would make your main code a lot shorter:

```
<View>
    <TotalItem title="Subtotal" amount={this.state.subtotal[0]}/>
    <TotalItem title="Tax Total" amount={this.state.tax_total[0]}/>
    <TotalItem title="Total" amount={this.state.total[0]}/>
    <TotalItem title="Total Orders" amount=this.state.total_orders[0]}/>

    <TotalItem title="Subtotal" amount={this.state.subtotal[1]}/>
    <TotalItem title="Tax Total" amount={this.state.tax_total[1]}/>
    <TotalItem title="Total" amount={this.state.total[1]}/>
    <TotalItem title="Total Orders" amount=this.state.total_orders[1]}/>

    <TotalItem title="Subtotal" amount={this.state.subtotal[2]}/>
    <TotalItem title="Tax Total" amount={this.state.tax_total[2]}/>
    <TotalItem title="Total" amount={this.state.total[2]}/>
    <TotalItem title="Total Orders" amount=this.state.total_orders[2]}/>
</View>
```

Then, you can use map to render the list.

Now your final code  may look like this:

```
<View>
{
    this.state.subtotal.map((item, i) => (
        <TotalItem title="Subtotal" amount={this.state.subtotal[i]}/>
        <TotalItem title="Tax Total" amount={this.state.tax_total[i]}/>
        <TotalItem title="Total" amount={this.state.total[i]}/>
        <TotalItem title="Total Orders" amount={this.state.total_orders[i]}/>
    ))
}
</View>
```

Notice I am using a crappy trick get the "i" index using this.state.subtotal because your data structure is not good at all.

What you currently have :

```
this.state = {
  Subtotal=[ 0, 1850, 2310.91, ]
  Tax_total=[ 0, 238.06, 369.1, ]
  Total=[ 0, 2088.06, 2680.01, ]
  Orders=[ 0, 7, 15, ]
}
```

This is not a good pattern because your objects are spread accross many fields. It's better to have distinct fields inside each object rather than having distinct object pieces inside fields.

What you want to do is:

```
this.state = {
  items: {
    [
      {subTotal:0, taxTotal:0, total:0, orders:0},
      {subTotal:1850, taxTotal:238, total:2088, orders:7},
      {subTotal:2310, taxTotal:369, total:2680, orders:15},
    ]
  }
}
```

And now you can map nicely without getting the values using the "i" index, and you finally get:

```
<View>
{
    this.state.items.map(item => (
        <TotalItem title="Subtotal" amount={item.subtotal}/>
        <TotalItem title="Tax Total" amount={item.taxTotal}/>
        <TotalItem title="Total" amount={item.total}/>
        <TotalItem title="Total Orders" amount={item.orders}/>
    ))
}
</View>
```

If you get the error "each value in a map must have a unique index", add an inner view with the "i" as key, but use the i only for the key, not to get array values:

```
<View>
{
    this.state.items.map((item,i) => (
      <View key={i}>
        <TotalItem title="Subtotal" amount={item.subtotal}/>
        <TotalItem title="Tax Total" amount={item.taxTotal}/>
        <TotalItem title="Total" amount={item.total}/>
        <TotalItem title="Total Orders" amount={item.orders}/>
      </View>
    ))
}
</View>
```