# Using .map to iterate on two different arrays at the same time

Tags: reactjs

I have two array of the same length, I would like to iterate on them and send the iterable to a new component.

The first array is `haircutsLeft`, the second is `haircutsRight`. Following this question: [Using map to iterate through two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42925805/using-map-to-iterate-through-two-arrays), I tried what they suggested with little success.

**First try**

```
export default function VotingComponent({haircutsLeft, haircutsRight}) {

    return(
        <Grid
            {haircutsLeft.map((haircutLeft, idx) =>
                <DisappearingComponent haircutLeft={haircutLeft} haircutsRight={haircutsRight[idx]} idx={idx}/>
            )}
        </Grid>
    )

}
```

> > It does not pass `haircutsRight={haircutsRightLoop[idx]}` to the `DisappearingComponent` because, if I console log it in `DisappearingComponent`, I get `undefined`

**Second try**

```
export default function VotingComponent({haircutsLeft, haircutsRight}) {

     haircutsLeft.map((haircutLeft, index) => {
         const haircutRight = haircutsRight[index];
         return (
             <div>
            <DisappearingComponent haircutLeft={haircutLeft} haircutsRight={haircutRight}/>

             </div>    
         );
     });
}
```

> > I get `VotingComponent(...): Nothing was returned from render.`

**Third try - Following the comment's advice**

```
export default function VotingComponent({haircutsLeft, haircutsRight}) {

    return haircutsLeft.map((haircutLeft, index) => {
        console.log(index)
        const haircutRight = haircutsRight[index];
        console.log(haircutRight)
        return (
            <div>
                <DisappearingComponent haircutLeft={haircutLeft} haircutsRight={haircutRight}/>
            </div>
        );
    });
}
```

> > I can console.log the `index` correctly, but `haircutRight` gives me `undefined`

**This is the component to which I am sending the props**

```
export default function DisappearingComponent({haircutLeft,  haircutRight}) {
    console.log("haircutLeft", haircutLeft) // Correct value
    console.log("haircutRight", haircutRight) // Undefined
    return(
            <div>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <LeftCard haircutLeft={haircutLeft} />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <RightCard haircutRight={haircutRight}/>
                </Grid>
            </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: Your third try should work. Does your `haircutsRight` has data in it? Also, is its length the same as `haircutsLeft`? As I've mentioned in my answer, this could work only if your second array is of same size as the first one.

Comment: Yes, both are from the same length. In the grandparent component I have a `haircuts` array of length 16 and I split it in half. However, now that you make me notice it, `haircutsRight` is empty even if in the grandparent component contains the right values. I will try to see what I did wrong. Thanks

Comment: Happy I could help you figure that out. Good luck with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your **first try** I can't spot your `haircutsRightLoop` anywhere. I think you are meant to use `haircutsRight` there. If both your `haircutsLeft` and `haircutsRight` arrays **are of the same length**, then your code should do the trick.

On your **second try**, you should also return your new array returned by `.map()`:

```js
export default function VotingComponent({haircutsLeft, haircutsRight}) {

     return haircutsLeft.map((haircutLeft, index) => {
         const haircutRight = haircutsRight[index];
         return (
             <div>
             <LeftCard haircutLeft={haircutLeft}/>
             <RightCard haircutRight={haircutRight} />
             </div>    
         );
     });
}
```

Comment: (and add a render method)

Comment: OP seems to work with functional component. `render` method is part of class components.

Comment: Yes, sorry. In first try I did `haircutsRight`, I corrected it. However, no success. I am using `Hooks`

Comment: (and both components params need to be refered to as "props", they're currently anonymous)

Comment: I tried both methods, but still the `haircutRight` gives me `undefined` if I console.log it in the component to which it is sent to

Comment: Can you also paste your code from your component which you pass `haircutRight` and you try to `console.log` it?

Comment: Also, did you try adding the `return` as suggest to your **second try**?

Comment: Yes, I updated my question merging in my third try your suggestions